# What do "marginal" and "conditional" mean in "marginal models" and "conditional models"?

Tags: panel-data

What do "marginal" and "conditional" mean in "marginal models" and "conditional models"?

Are they related to marginal distributions and conditional distributions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say yes. But can you give some context?

Comment: @ziggystar: Its context is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/difference-between-marginal-and-conditional-models. How are they related to marginal and conditional distributions?

Answer (score 5):

In longitudinal data analysis, marginal models refers to population average models, e.g., generalized estimating equations (GEE) models; conditional models refers to subject specific models, e.g., mixed-effects models. The two models address different questions.

- Let's start from a **linear** mixed-effects model, $$
     y_{ij}=\mathbf{x}_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol{\beta}+\mathbf
     {z}_{ij}^{'}\mathbf{u}_i+\epsilon_{ij}.$$

  The mean of outcome conditional on the random effects $\mathbf{u}_i$
  is  $$\mu_{ij}^c=E(y_{ij}|\mathbf u_i)=\mathbf
     x_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol\beta + \mathbf z_{ij}^{'}\mathbf u_i,$$ and the
  marginal mean of outcome (average over the distribution of random
  effects) is  $$\mu_{ij}^m=E(y_{ij})=E(E(y_{ij}|\mathbf u_i))=\mathbf
     x_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol\beta,$$ since we assume $\mathbf u_i$ has mean 0. The $\boldsymbol\beta$ coincides in marginal and conditional models.
- However, for **nonlinear** models, $\boldsymbol\beta$ in the two models
  would differ in both interpretation (population average vs. subject
  specific) and scale of coefficients, 
  $$E(\mu_{ij}^c)=E(h^{-1}(\mathbf x_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol\beta^c +
     \mathbf z_{ij}^{'}\mathbf u_i))\neq h^{-1}(\mathbf
     x_{ij}^{'}\boldsymbol\beta^m)=\mu_{ij}^m,$$ where $h$ is the link
  function, e.g., logit or probit link for binary data, log link for
  count data.