# How to fit a mixed model to this advertising data?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have data on about 20000 consumers who were exposed to some form of advertising. The data is in the following form.

```
Cookie_Id   Observation_Number  Ad_Id   Ad_Id_Lookup    Placement_Id    Placement_Category  Placement_Cpi   Cookie_Lookup
2   1   325 Standard    3722    News    20  0
3   1   325 Standard    3722    News    20  0
4   1   325 Standard    3719    Weather 8   2
4   2   325 Standard    3719    Weather 8   2
5   1   324 Standard    3718    Weather 8   0
5   2   324 Standard    3718    Weather 8   0
6   1   327 Rich-Media  3716    Travel  20  0
6   2   327 Rich-Media  3716    Travel  20  0
6   3   327 Rich-Media  3716    Travel  20  0
6   4   327 Rich-Media  3716    Travel  20  0
7   1   324 Standard    3718    Weather 8   1
7   2   324 Standard    3718    Weather 8   1
8   1   323 Standard    3717    Weather 8   0
8   2   323 Standard    3717    Weather 8   0
9   1   325 Standard    3719    Weather 8   0
9   2   325 Standard    3719    Weather 8   0
11  1   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
11  2   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
11  3   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
11  4   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
12  1   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
12  2   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
12  3   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
12  4   324 Standard    3713    Travel  12  0
13  1   327 Rich-Media  3723    News    28  0
14  1   325 Standard    3722    News    20  0
15  1   325 Standard    3722    News    20  0
```

I'm looking to model the data using a linear mixed model, with Ad_Id_Lookup and Placement_Category as input variables and Cookie_Lookup as my output variable (the states 0,1 and 2 correspond to different outcomes, such as whether someone made a purchase).

The trouble is that many of the rows are identical to each other, other than the observation number (this ordering is a bit artificial because I don't have time stamps). I want to treat each ad exposure as a new treatment on each individual cookie ID.

Can I do this using the nlme package in R? If not, is there another package that can deal with data of this type?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lme in nlme is designed for linear mixed effects models, meaning that the outcome variable at least approximates a continuous outcome. However, what exactly Cookie-Lookup is will determine what package you need to find. Here are a few things to choose from:

1. Does the 0, 1, 2 in the outcome represent a count? If so, then you can use lme4 and model the data as a Poisson distribution. Although using GEE with the gee or geepack packages may be better if you're interested in a marginal, rather than subject-specific, interpretation. Here's a [description](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/difference-between-marginal-and-conditional-models) of the two.
2. If the 0, 1, and 2 are simply different categories without any logical order, then you need to perform multinomial regression that accounts for the multiple observations per subject. Again, a GEE model may be the way to go. I found [nomLORgee](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/multgee/docs/nomLORgee), but I haven't used it or analyzed this kind of longitudinal data.
3. Lastly, if the two predictor variables are not time-varying, then you could simply take the person-average of his or her outcome, and analyze the data using a cross-sectional multinomial model, such as multinom in the [nnet package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/index.html) and some [helpful examples](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm). This last method is somewhat crude, but without time-stamps, you would otherwise be attempting to model longitudinal data with a dubious estimate of time.